# Laravel homestead suddenly stopped using 8000 port suffix when submitting forms

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, vagrant, homestead

I have a form that looks like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('flyers.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="col-md-6">
        @include('flyers.form')
    </form>
```

Throughout the entirety of the project, this worked. It would post to my local development url http://projectflyer.dev:8000/flyers.

Suddenly it's posting to http://projectflyer.dev/flyers.

I'm not sure what would cause this. Any suggestions?

Another interesting development: When I type http://projectflyer.dev:8000/flyers directly into the browser, it redirects to http://projectflyer.dev/flyers.

Routes file looks like:

```
<?php

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('pages.home');
    });

    Route::resource('flyers', 'FlyersController');
    Route::get('{zip}/{street}', 'FlyersController@show');
    Route::post('{zip}/{street}/photos', ['as' =>'store_photo_path', 'uses' => 'FlyersController@addPhoto']);

});
```

Comment: Does the same happen with just normal links?

Comment: No, it appears to be just form actions. Even if I use "/flyers" as the action instead of a named route, I get the same.

Comment: But you are using the Laravel UrlGenerator to build those other links, right?

Comment: No, mostly providing direct paths.

Comment: Did you configure your url in the .env file? If so, change the url to include the port number

Comment: I set the APP_URL to http://projectflyer.dev:8000. Same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens as a result of having a route post to 'flyers' when also having a public directory called 'flyers'.